# Why is SqlQuery a lot faster than using LINQ expression on views?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, oracle11g

I want to query data from a view, which is a view of a table contains 583,000 records.
So I write a simple query to query from the view like this

```
var uuid = "AB1-23456";
dbSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserKey == uuid);
```

This is the generated sql

```
SELECT "Extent1"."UserKey" AS "UserKey", 
       CAST("Extent1"."IsDeleted" AS number(3,0)) AS "C1", 
       "Extent1"."FirstName" AS "FirstName", 
       "Extent1"."LastName" AS "LastName", 
       "Extent1"."UserLogin" AS "UserLogin", 
       "Extent1"."AccLocationKey" AS "AccLocationKey", 
       "Extent1"."CompanyKey" AS "CompanyKey"
FROM "UsersView" "Extent1"
WHERE ('AB1-23456' = "Extent1"."UserKey")
```

I ran the query for 5 times.
The first call took me **350ms** and next calls took me **150ms** on average on this query which was too slow, so I changed the query to be like this

```
var queryString = 
    "SELECT \"Extent1\".\"UserKey\" AS \"UserKey\", " +
            "CAST( \"Extent1\".\"IsDeleted\" AS number(3,0)) AS \"IsDeleted\", " +
            "\"Extent1\".\"FirstName\" AS \"FirstName\", " +
            "\"Extent1\".\"LastName\" AS \"LastName\", " +
            "\"Extent1\".\"UserLogin\" AS \"UserLogin\", " +
            "\"Extent1\".\"AccLocationKey\" AS \"AccLocationKey\", " +
            "\"Extent1\".\"CompanyKey\" AS \"CompanyKey\" " +
    "FROM \"UsersView\" \"Extent1\" " +
    "WHERE ('AB1-23456' = \"Extent1\".\"UserKey\")";
dbSet.SqlQuery(queryString).SingleOrDefault();
```

I ran it for 5 times
The first call took me **40ms** and next calls took me only **1ms** on average!

Do anyone has any ideas what I did wrong?

**Environment**

- Entity Framework 5.0
- Oracle 11g Database
- ODP.NET 11.2 Release 3
- .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Is this reproducable? What happens if you send the queries using your new query first? Will the generated query be the fast one?

Comment: I highly doubt your "generated sql" is accurately represented here.  EF would most likely use parameters, and not embed a string literal in the query like you show.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I used LinqPad to generate the SQL statement and it showed me that statement.

Comment: @nvoigt I've tried calling those two queries in different order, the result is still the same.

Comment: are you getting these time results from LinqPad? Because if you're using LinqPad, I don't think your linq queries will be cached. So it practically doesn't matter how many times you run (aside from query plan caching on the DB side maybe).

Comment: @ErenErsönmez No, I capture the time spent in the program itself. I use LinqPad to only generate the SQL statement.

Comment: ok, then you might take a look at [compiled queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896297(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if that makes a significant difference.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Seems like Compiled Query is not available in DbContext. I don't use ObjectContext. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b8315b3-eb0c-4115-92e6-b63914ab0cec/how-can-compiled-query-work-with-dbcontext?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: @Moozz it can be used on DataContext (a wrapper for ObjectContext)... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb399335%28v=vs.90%29.aspx .. although this will of course slow down first execution but speed up subsequent executions.

Comment: @Moozz you can retrieve the ObjectContext from DbContext easily: `var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;`

Comment: @ErenErsönmez EF5 and above automatically caches the query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739925/entity-framework-compiled-query

Comment: You may be right, I didn't try this myself. However, the note on the MSDN doc is interesting `Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, LINQ queries are cached automatically. However, you can still use compiled LINQ queries to reduce this cost in later executions and compiled queries can be more efficient than LINQ queries that are automatically cached.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best answer to this question.

https://community.oracle.com/message/10481253

Answer (score 4):

Isn't it that it takes that 150ms only **the first time it ran**?. Every consecutive call should take around that 1ms you stated. LinqToSql has to compile the query first to get SQL.
Take a look at 
[LinqToSql Precompiling queries benefit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873984/linqtosql-precompiling-queries-benefit)

Comment: No, it is 150ms every time it is run.

Comment: To be more clear, I ran it for many time without restarting the process, The first call took me 350ms and next calls took me 150ms on average.

Comment: I found that EF5 automatically caches the query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739925/entity-framework-compiled-query

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not valid anymore.

```
var uuid = "AB1-23456";
dbSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserKey == uuid);
```

The time spent is around **150ms**. But if I tried

```
dbSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserKey == "AB1-23456");
```

The time spent is back to **1ms**. I'll ask an another question accordingly.

Comment: Odd... What if you use string uuid = "AB1-23456"; ?

Comment: Did you try query expression? e.g. (from x in dbSet where x.UserKey = uuid select x).SingleOrDefault(); Was there any difference? - Just curious.

Comment: @PaulZahra The result is the same as .SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserKey == uuid). And if I change to string literal, the result is the same as SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserKey == "AB1-23456");

Comment: Strange... this may interest you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh949853.aspx

Comment: I suspect that the reason maybe because of the way it constructs the cache for the query, the string literal will be defined as a constant, the variable will be parameterised, although I can't see it making that much difference.